# milo: Bad_SessionIdInvalid "The session id is not valid."

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am getting a "The session id is not valid." exception when reading the value of a node ,but just sometimes,I konw the session is not timeout,so why?

the exception ：

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SessionIdInvalid, message=The session id is not valid.
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
at com.ggnykj.smartems.cloud.server.autocontrol.client.OpcClientServer.readNode(OpcClientServer.java:230)
at com.ggnykj.smartems.cloud.server.autocontrol.controller.OpcClientServerController.readNode(OpcClientServerController.java:115)
at com.ggnykj.smartems.cloud.server.autocontrol.server.SaveExOpcData.run(SaveExOpcData.java:59)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SessionIdInvalid, message=The session id is not valid.
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient.lambda$receiveResponse$16(UaTcpStackClient.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.ExecutionQueue$PollAndExecute.run(ExecutionQueue.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    ... 3 more
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ggnykj.smartems.cloud.server.autocontrol.controller.OpcClientServerController.readNode(OpcClientServerController.java:116)
    at com.ggnykj.smartems.cloud.server.autocontrol.server.SaveExOpcData.run(SaveExOpcData.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

my code：

MyX509IdentityProvider x509IdentityProvider = new MyX509IdentityProvider(clientOption.opcServer.getCertFilePath(),
                clientOption.opcServer.getPrivateKeyPath());
        X509Certificate cert = x509IdentityProvider.getCertificate();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(cert.getPublicKey(), x509IdentityProvider.getPrivateKey());

```
    OpcUaClientConfig config = OpcUaClientConfig.builder()
        .setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english(clientOption.opcServer.getOpcServerName()))
        //.setApplicationUri("urn:eclipse:milo:examples:client")
        .setApplicationUri("")
        //.setCertificate(loader.getClientCertificate())
        //.setKeyPair(loader.getClientKeyPair())
        .setCertificate(cert)
        .setKeyPair(keyPair)
        .setEndpoint(endpoint)
        .setIdentityProvider(clientOption.getIdentityProvider())
        .setChannelLifetime(uint(600000000))
        .setSessionTimeout(uint(600000000))
        //.setRequestTimeout(uint(5000))
        .build();

    return new OpcUaClient(config);
```

---

```
 private OpcUaClient getOpcClient(OpcServer opcServer){
    OpcUaClient client = null;
    if(null!=opcClientMap.get(opcServer.getOpcServerId())){
        client = opcClientMap.get(opcServer.getOpcServerId());
    }else{
        try {
            ClientOption clientOption = new ClientOption(opcServer);
            client =  new ClientOptionRunner(clientOption).createClient();
        }catch (Throwable t){
            logger.error("Error getting client: {}", t.getMessage(), t);
        }
        opcClientMap.put(opcServer.getOpcServerId(),client);
    }
    return client;
```

### }

```
public DataValue readNode(OpcServer opcServer,NodeId nodeId){
    OpcUaClient client = getOpcClient(opcServer);
    DataValue value = null;

    try {
        client.connect().get();  
        value = client.readValue(0.0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, nodeId).get(); 
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: How do you know that the session has not timed out?

Comment: this is my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [milo:Bad\_SessionIdInvalid, The session id is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008517/milobad-sessionidinvalid-the-session-id-is-not-valid)